# VS Code : Azure : Open Bash in Cloud Shell , Select directory.. hang

Tags: c#, bash, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-cloud-shell

in Visual Studio Code, I did Azure Sign In. Then Azure : Open Bash in Cloud Shell. It prompts for Directory. When I select the 1 desired, nothing happen. Please help. Ref below:-
[image: Azure : Open Bash in Cloud Shell]

Comment: FYI, you can access Azure Shell directly as well. Just go to https://shell.azure.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you are on the latest version of VS Code. I'm on `1.39.2` and the following works for me:

- From the command palette, sign in to Azure using `Azure: Sign in`.
- Then `Azure: Open Bash in Cloud Shell`, like you mentioned.
- Upon selecting your directory, you'll see something like this:
  [image: Directory setup needed]
- As the pop up in the bottom right corner shows, the first launch of Cloud Shell in a directory requires setup in the web application. Click on `Open`.
- You'll see a prompt similar to this:
  [image: Open Link]
- Clicking on `Open Link` will open up https://shell.azure.com. Sign in to your account there.
- Once that is done, perform `Azure: Open Bash in Cloud Shell` again. Now that you're signed in to Azure on Cloud Shell, you'll see this on your VS Code window:
  [image: Signed in]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug see [Azure Account Git Repo Issue 220](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azure-account/issues/220)

Comment: Please add a more detail of your link